# is it possible to post two datas in one column in mysql database?

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

What I want to do is I want to post two datas in one table but I don't know if it's possible or not. Is there any way that a column can hadle two datas or more at once?

[Here is the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZOZz.png)

Like for example I have two monitors that I want for my unit. But from what I can see from the database only the first field gets recorded not the added field. As you can see I have a little function where I can add and delete fields in categories where items can be multiple or not.

[Here is my table that I want to send the datas in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3so8.png)

Comment: The propper way are multiple tables because you're trying to make a many to many relation (https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab). I would suggest that for you. Theres no normal way to store multiple informations in one column.

Comment: Okay, thank you I will study this one. Thank you so much

Comment: For example for the monitor: You have a table `monitors` where all monitors are stored and a table `system_units` (your existing table). Now you need an another table called (for example) `system_unit_monitors`. There you store the id of the system unit table and the monitor table to connect it with each other.

Comment: Oh so its a threeway-table, I now have a good idea to do it thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really look into database normalization. 
With your current table structure, there's no efficient way to do what you need (because you only have one field for storing each type of component.
A workaround would be to convert each field that could potentially hold multiple user selections to a JSON type and store them there. (all it takes would be to build a `$monitors` array and then convert it to json (with `json_encode($monitors)` prior to inserting. This, while feasible, has some drawbacks in terms of efficiency and indexability/searchability

what you really need is, like I said earlier, normalizing your tables.

You should have a "pivot" table (let's call it "assemblies") and separate component tables (call them what you want, but it could be "monitors", "cpus", "memory" etc).
When assembling a new device, you'd create a new "assembly" and insert the components in their respective table with a reference to the master "assemblies" table
By doing this, you could have a single assembly referencing multiple entries in the "monitors" table because this structure allows establishing "one-to-many" relationships

I strongly suggest you get your feet wet with normalization. Wikipedia could be a good starting point [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

A more in depth explanation with examples can be found [HERE](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: thank you I tried doing this `'monitor'=>json_encode(implode(",", $this->input->post('monitor'))),` and it now saves as two data in one column. Now the data type that is my column that was inserted, do I have to change it as a JSON data type? because I set it as an integer for now and works fine. Thank you for answering sir

Comment: Without seeing  your code it's hard to guess what you did and what you managed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can store json object in json datatype and application level you can access

Comment: Im not really familiar with json sorry

Comment: not a good idea because it lacks indexability and is not compliant with any normal form (see: [database normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) ).. plus, when you need to store data as JSON (yes, there's valid reasons to store JSON objects sometimes) you should use a  `JSON` datatype, not a `VARCHAR`

Comment: Do I really have to change it as a JSON?Thank you for answering

Comment: If you plan to store as `json` datatype, then yes. Otherwise you may encounter data getting truncated upon insertion. Also, while it's more efficient to parse a json after retrieving it from the database, using a json datatype would allow to do some advance querying with pure vanilla SQL. I'd rather suggest you look into database normalization (see my answer above). It'll save you a lot of performance trouble in the future