# Codeigniter problem, Does JSON datatype array is read as one?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

This is a continuation from my past question which is this [is it possible to post two datas in one column in mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832410/is-it-possible-to-post-two-datas-in-one-column-in-mysql-database)

Its affecting my Peripherals table which is the picture below[image]

I was supposed to deploy 2 monitors and 2 rams. My datatype that I used for my monitor, ram, lan_card, and hdd is JSON. Is it because I used JSON as a datatype that it will only read as one data? Im still studying relationship types and I'm afraid doing anything to my database. I will change my database structure later on but for now I want to experiment with JSON. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Here is my database for which the quantity table depends on
[image]

Comment: can you give us more detail about your question?

Comment: If I post two datas in one column(from what you can see from my database table picture above I have 4 columns in json datatype and each has 2 datas in their array)does get read the column as one or not two? Because its affecting my quantity table instead of 2 deployed I only get 1 deployed from those columns